# Which standard resources are used in android "unread counter"?

Tags: android, resources, android-widget, widget

Need to find "green circle" badge icon, font name, style and size and position of that circle relative to application icon. Where can I find that? Probably, some android sources?

Comment: Where does this "unread counter" appear?  I can't figure out exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This is on the home screen, on the top of icons of such applications like SMS, e-mail etc.

Comment: Hmm. Probably it is red on standard Android and green on HTC? Then probably the icon I am looking for is _ic_notification_overlay.9.png_?

Comment: That is what I think as well, yes.

Comment: I'll just add that if you are doing this for a notification in the status bar, the system will handle overlaying the count for you automatically based on the Notification.number setting.

Comment: @slund, I need to create a widget on the home screen, not notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, analysis of Google Reader xml files helped me.